# Find center of mass for image along axis

Tags: numpy, scipy, python-3.6

I am trying to find a center of mass for each column of the image. I currently use `scipy.ndimage.measurements.center_of_mass` module and simple iteration to do that. My current code is:

```
def get_y_vec(img):

    out = []

    for col in img.T: 
        out.append(np.around(measurements.center_of_mass(col)[0], 1))

    out = np.array(out)

    return out
```

This works and produces pretty good results, however, it is pretty slow. Is there a more performant alternative to do achieve same output?

EDIT:

I just realised that center of mass is a fairly straightforward maths and can be written as such:

```
get_com = lambda m: np.round(np.sum(np.arange(m.shape[0])*m)/np.sum(m), 1)


def get_y_vec(img):

    out = np.apply_along_axis(get_com, 0, img)

    return out
```

While it's 4x faster, my images are fairly large and I feel like we can come up with fully vectorized solution instead of using `np.apply_along_axis` or iteration.

Comment: No need to compute it twice - `com` seems to be unused.

Comment: @kazemakase sorry my bad, in the code I am not actually computing it twice. I will edit question now.

Comment: Too bad, this would have been an easy optimization :) What does the input `img` look like (typical shape and value range)?

Comment: it is a 2d array of shape ~ 200x1800. Values range from 0 to 255. I came up with a slightly faster way of doing that. I can simply use numpy implementation of center of mass function: `np.round(np.sum(np.arange(m.shape[0])*m)/np.sum(m), 1)`. While it's faster, I was wondering if there's perhaps some numpy-magic vectorized version of it :)

Comment: I was about to suggest something similar. What is `m` in your numpy implementation - a single column or the whole image?

Comment: m is a single column, see edit that I just made

Comment: Almost there... You might use `np.apply_along_axis(ndimage.measurements.center_of_mass,0,img)` that should handle it faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second version is slightly faster, but it can be made still faster using vectorization. (`apply_along_axis` just hides a loop):

```
def get_y_vec(img, axis=0):
    n = img.shape[axis]
    s = [1] * img.ndim
    s[axis] = -1
    i = np.arange(n).reshape(s)
    return np.round(np.sum(img * i, axis=axis) / np.sum(img, axis=axis), 1)
```

The code is a bit more complicated than necessary because it can handle images of any dimension and the center of gravity along any axis. The basic idea is to create an index vector with `arange` and perform a weighted summation over the indices with the image values as weights (exactly as in the OP's second solution).

A simpler version, that only works along columns would look like this:

```
def get_y_vec(img):
    n = img.shape[0]
    i = np.arange(n).reshape([n, 1])
    return np.round(np.sum(img * i, axis=0) / np.sum(img, axis=0), 1)
```

It utilizes two vectorization features of numpy: broadcasting and summation along an axis. First, an index array is created with the same number of rows as in the image, but only one column. In `img * i` the vector is automatically multiplied with every column in the image (this is broadcasting). Then, by passing `axis=0` we instruct `sum` to work on each column independently, resulting in one value for each column.

Timing comparison:

```
10 loops, best of 3: 71.8 ms per loop   # scipy
10 loops, best of 3: 42.7 ms per loop   # apply_along_axis
100 loops, best of 3: 1.67 ms per loop  # vectorized
```

40x speedup doesn't seem too bad :)

Benchmark code (IPython):

```
img = np.random.randint(256, size=(200, 1800))
%timeit get_y_vec(img)
```

Comment: That's great, thanks a lot! Do you mind explaining how code works?

Comment: I've updated the answer with some explanation. Code comes easier to me than words... hope it helps anyway :)